# Testing HttpClient call with callFake()

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, httpclient

I am trying to create a spec to test a method in my Angular service that makes a GET request.  The difficulty I am having is mocking the method to get it to return an error instead of the response.  If I cannot get it to return an error (such a 400 or 500 for example) I cannot provide full code coverage...

Code being tested:

maingrid.service.ts:

```
 async loadAccountListPromise(id: string) {
     let queryParams = `?emailAddress=${id}`;
     let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}` + queryParams, { responseType: 'json' })
             .toPromise()
             .then(
             (data) => {
                 this.results = this.formatData(data);
                 resolve(this.results);
             },
             (err) => {
                 this.logService.error('loadAccountListPromise() exception:', err);
                 this.setError(this.message[0], err);
                 reject('loadAccountListPromise() exception');
             }
         );
     });
     return promise;
 }

 setError(errorMessage: string, errorCode?: string): void {
     this._error.next(new NxpError(errorMessage, 'AccountListService', 
     errorCode));
 }

 clearError(): void {
     this._error.next(null);
 }
```

This is the spec I have attempted to write to mock the method using callFake():

maingrid.service.spec.ts

```
    it('logs and sets a local error for system errors/exceptions', () => {

            let id: string = 'ppandya@pershing.com';
            let myUrl = 'https://localhost:9999/...';
            let queryParams = `?emailAddress=${id}`;

            spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.callFake( loadAccountListPromise( (response) => {
                // need to return error here...somehow
            }));

            spyOn(logService, 'error');

            spyOn(maingridService, 'setError');

            maingridService.loadAccountListPromise(id);

            let request = httpMock.expectOne(myUrl + queryParams);

            expect(request.request.method).toEqual('GET');

            httpMock.verify();

            expect(logService.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(maingridService.setError).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

I am not sure what I need to do to properly mock the loadAcountListPromise() method so that it enters the error block and calls the `setError()` and `logService.error()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the 'spyOn()' and return a throw like this:

```
spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({status: 404}));
//Observable.throw(new Error(`Error: ${error}`));
```

Comment: Ok I see the general idea but what exactly is 'Observable' in this case?  Do I need to add that as a provider in my TestBed?  `Observable` get a ts error of 'cannot find name Observable" . I assume I `import` it from Rxjs...?

Comment: Import it `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; `

Comment: Yes got that I'll try now

Comment: Now it is throwing an error, but now my `httpMock.expectOne(url)` fails as expected I am not sure how to I follow the code path past this point to get the `expect(logService.error).toHaveBeenCalled()` to pass